# how to refresh the edittext after the alertdialog is closed

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, android-lifecycle, fragment-lifecycle

I want to change the values of the 3 edittexts after the user presses confirm in the alertdialog.But it is not refreshing.the values are only changing after moving to some other fragment and coming back to this fragment

```
SharedPreferences sp;
EditText ip,port,appkey;
Button connect;

public ConnectFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_connect, container, false);
    ip= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editid);
    port= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editport);
    appkey= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editsppKey);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"oncreateview",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    sp=getActivity().getSharedPreferences("connection", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ip.setText(sp.getString("ip",null));
    port.setText(sp.getString("port",null));
    appkey.setText(sp.getString("appkey",null));
    connect= (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.connectf);
   connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            senddata();
        }
    });
    return v;
}
private void senddata() {
    //senddata

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"on Activity Created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    sp=getActivity().getSharedPreferences("connection", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ip.setText(sp.getString("ip",null));
    port.setText(sp.getString("port",null));
    appkey.setText(sp.getString("appkey",null));
}


@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment childFragment) {
    super.onAttachFragment(childFragment);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"On Attach Fragment",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    sp=getActivity().getSharedPreferences("connection", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ip.setText(sp.getString("ip",null));
    port.setText(sp.getString("port",null));
    appkey.setText(sp.getString("appkey",null));
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"On Resume",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    sp=getActivity().getSharedPreferences("connection", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ip.setText(sp.getString("ip",null));
    port.setText(sp.getString("port",null));
    appkey.setText(sp.getString("appkey",null));
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"stop",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"pause",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (this.isVisible()) {
        // If we are becoming invisible, then...
        if (!isVisibleToUser) {
            sp=getActivity().getSharedPreferences("connection", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ip.setText(sp.getString("ip",null));
            port.setText(sp.getString("port",null));
            appkey.setText(sp.getString("appkey",null));
            Log.d("MyFragment", "Not visible anymore.  Stopping audio.");
            // TODO stop audio playback
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"On start",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    sp=getActivity().getSharedPreferences("connection", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ip.setText(sp.getString("ip",null));
    port.setText(sp.getString("port",null));
    appkey.setText(sp.getString("appkey",null));
}
```

}

//here is my dialog in the activity

```
final View v=LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.formlayout,null);
       AlertDialog.Builder ab=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        ab.setView(v);
        tp= (TextInputLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ip);
        tp1= (TextInputLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.port);
        tp2= (TextInputLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.appkey);

        ab.setTitle("Enter Connection Details");
        ab.setPositiveButton("confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                String a=tp.getEditText().getText().toString();
                String b=tp1.getEditText().getText().toString();
                String c=tp2.getEditText().getText().toString();
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(a)&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(b) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(c))
                {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit=sp.edit();
                    edit.putString("ip",a);
                    edit.putString("port",b);
                    edit.putString("appkey",c);
                    edit.commit();
                }
            }
        });
        ab.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        AlertDialog abc=ab.create();
        abc.show();
        abc.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: You can use dialogue dismiss listener to refresh your view.

Comment: where is your dialogue in your code?

Comment: how to refresh the views of the fragment dialog dismiss listener

Comment: @Sandeepdhiman hii I added the dialog code here .Can you please lgo through that

Comment: I am having 3 tabs with a viewpager and I just want to know which lifecycle method is called when i move away from one fragment and move into the another fragment. beacause onStart(),onResume(),onActivityCreated() are not being called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
abc.show();
abc.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        fragmentInstance.refreshEditTextValue(value);
    }
 });
```

In your fragment :

```
 public refreshEditTextValue(String value) {
//TODO set value in edittext
    }
```